# MongoDB stops working after some time

Tags: ubuntu, mongodb

I have installed MongoDB 3.2 into my Ubuntu 16.04 server.
At the beginning work but after some time it stops working giving this error :

```
E QUERY [thread1] Error : network error while attempting to run command 'isMaster' on host '127.0.0.1:27017'
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:229:14
@(connect):1:6

exception: connect failed
```

I already tried the solutions proposed in some forums but have not worked.

Comment: Please help, I am desperate

Comment: Is this problem already solved? It looks like you got some sharding configuration problems.

Comment: i have not solved it, now i use mongodb atlas...